# how can we get MAX value hold in a field from Amazon Dynamodb?

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using Amazon Dynamodb. I would like to know that, how can we fetch MAX value hold in a field from Amazon Dynamodb table. Please let me know, if you have solution

Comment: Did you find an answer for this question?

Answer (score 1):

This is the first example in the Amazon DynamoDB documentation:

> **To find the largest value for a mapped column (max)**
>
> Use Hive commands like the following. In the first command, the CREATE
>   statement creates a Hive table that references data stored in Amazon
>   DynamoDB. The SELECT statement then uses that table to query data
>   stored in Amazon DynamoDB. The following example finds the largest
>   order placed by a given customer.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hive_purchases(customerId bigint, total_cost double,
 items_purchased array<String>)

STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "Purchases",
"dynamodb.column.mapping" = "customerId:CustomerId,total_cost:Cost,items_pur 
chased:Items");

SELECT max(total_cost) from hive_purchases where customerId = 717;
```

Answer (score -1):

Every time you update an item, you can compare it with the max. Replace the max item with the larger one.